# Migrating from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.0 resulting in Could not load type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-3.1

I've recently been trying to migrate an existing .NET Core 2.2 WEB API project to .NET Core 3.1 with the aim of first migrating from .NET Core 2.2 to 3.0 then to 3.1.

This solution contains contains several .NET Core 2.2 class libraries and a .NET Core 2.2 Web Api project with their corresponding test projects.

I am currently facing an issue that I am not able to find the solution to yet and hoping someone here can enlighten or guide to the solution.

So to the point, I've been going through the official documentation on [Migrating from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) and managed to make all the changes necessary and have the solution successfully rebuild but for some reason I keep getting the below exception when I run web api test project.

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException : Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
    Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorTemplateEngine' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

Here is the api project package references:

[image]

and its corresponding test project references:

[image]

I am thinking it may be something to do with packages either in the above screenshots or the class libraries that the web api project depends on ? or missing something?

Now I've researched and looked into this exception thoroughly from Github, SO and other sources for hours in the hope of getting to the solution but to no avail.

If anyone can shed some light on this that would be great. Let me know in comments if you need me to provide anymore info or if you have any questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not really a solution, but if I were in your situation, I would create a new project and compare the references.

Comment: @Llama Yup done that too but a new .NET core project barely contains any references. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: [The `RazorTemplateEngine` class docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.razortemplateengine?view=aspnetcore-1.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0) say it was included in ASP.NET Core 1.0 and 1.1, but I wasn't able to find it in [Release `3.0.0`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/releases/tag/v3.0.0). Interestingly, the newer releases do include [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Razor/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language) but again, no `RazorTemplateEngine` that I could find.

Comment: ...Not sure what's depending on `RazorTemplateEngine` either.

Comment: Any chance [Release `3.1.0`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/releases/tag/v3.1.0) works for you? Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62172228/could-not-load-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-razor-language-razortemplateengine).

Comment: @DM Thanks for the find. I've currently got two feature branches. one feature branch  already has this project migrated to 3.1 and the same issue persists and the other feature branch has it migrated to 3.0 with the intention of figuring out whether this Razor issue is only 3.0 specific. However both migrations to .net core 3.0 and 3.1  result in the same error

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408993/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-apiexplorer-in-my-net) referencing the [ASP.NET Test Preqrequistes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.0#test-app-prerequisites)?

Comment: The [RazorTemplateEngine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.language.razortemplateengine?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class only applies to 2.X version of asp.net core, and the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.dll 3.1.10` version doesn't contains this class, so you have to remove the RazorTemplateEngine in the .Net Core 3 application.

Comment: how do you mean exactly by "remove the RazorTemplateEngine". I am not currently referencing any `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor...` explicitly.

Comment: @DM had a look into the question and prerequisites. I've done as the Microsoft tests  prerequisites suggests but still same issue. it's worth noting that I can run my application successfully via F5 but when I run the tests I get the said error. **However I don't necessarily thing it's test project related. it's just that running the application alone isn't triggering much work whereas the tests are actually invoking different pieces of components to make sure they work individually and as a group and during this process the tests have found that the said error is causing issues**